# Problem with jQuery post and (dynamic?) vars

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hey I got a working jquery post function, but it's still not working as I want it to work. The var "url" should be a an url as in the regex pattern below, when it matches the regex pattern jquery should post a request with the url in it to my php file, after that it will return a unique ref id and rewrite the url to a new one on my own site like example.org/ref.php?id=unique1235 (the url rewrite/replace with unique generated string from php script works already perfectly.)

My JQuery function looks like this:

```
    $(".url2").keyup(validNum).blur(validNum);

    var refid;

    var url;  // needs to be extracted from the live input textarea with the pattern below that is used to replace the old url with the new one coming from the post php script

    $.ajax({                     url: "/test.php",
                                 data: {
                                 url: url
                                 },
                                 type: "POST",
                                 success:function(returnID) {
                                 refid = returnID 
                                     }
                                });




    function validNum() {
     var initVal = $(this).val();
    outputVal = initVal.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?[0-9A-Za-z-]{2,50}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}([\/\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#]){0,250}(\s){1}$/
,refid);  
    if (initVal != outputVal) {
        $(this).val(outputVal);
        return false;
        }}
});
```

I'm unable to "live"-extract the url from my textarea and save it to "var url" so that it can be passed and send to the php script where the old url gets saved and replace by an unique string (as described above). Would be so glad if someone is able to help me. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're triggering the $.ajax() directly, it's like "Everytime the document loads, that empty request loads, and it doesn't load more". Put it on a function, like this:

```
   function request_my_URL(){
          var refid;
           var url=$('.url2').val();      
           $.ajax({              url: "/test.php",
                                 data: {
                                 url: url
                                 },
                                 type: "POST",
                                 success:function(returnID) {
                                 refid = returnID;
                                 alert(refid);
                                     }
                                });
   }
```

Now, call the function in the click event of some button, for example:

```
   <textarea class='url2'></textarea>
   <input type='button' value='Get the URL!' onClick='request_my_URL();' />
```

It's your turn to modify this to work as you expect :D

Good Luck ;)

**EDIT:**

For live checking, you can use this:

```
$(".url2").keyup(function(){validNum(); request_my_URL();}).blur(function(){validNum(); request_my_URL();});
```

Comment: hm thank you! My problem is, that the check should be live ;(

Comment: yea it should check the input for url live, as the functions also replaces urls live after typing them in. If someone types in "hallo example.org this is my page" it replaces the url with "var refid"(my.site/ref.php?id=unique_ref_id) as soon as the user hits space after "hallo example.org". So i need to check live for an url input as well, then save it to "var url", send the var to my php file and then continue with the already working replace function.

Comment: Hey Ryan, first of all thanks a lot for a your effort. But seems i'm still too stupid to get it done. My code looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/DQHNM/ right now, trying to get it work for hours now, probably there's just a small error in it but I can get it working ;(

Comment: Thank you man, you are great but I think you didn't understand right. I have a textarea, where the user can type in anything he wants, of course also valid urls. So what I'm trying is to check the textarea for a valid url that is matching my pattern, this url should be saved as a var and send to my php file where if save it to my database and create a unique string that is returned to the jquery function. When all that is done, the old typed in url should be replace via my working function to the new ref url. It should be pretty much the same funcation as on bit.ly (twittershare for reg users)

Comment: The user should be able to write further content after the url so probably something like this could stand in the text area: "hallo visit my http://websi.te (saves url as var, excutes script, replace old site with my.site/ref.php?id=unique1234 [everything live]) thank you guys" is it understandable what i mean? :D

Comment: thanks man you are the best working perfectly fine, just one question. Is there a possiblity to stop or delay the function, because i found out if you are typing in a domain really fast and the shortlink isnt yet fully generated the same url is saved with 2 different unique ids. So I mean is it possible to stop till function finally created the new link and then a person can continue typing his message? :D

Comment: ah and found out, if you are pressing backspace after url was transformed (so if you try to remove the url from textarea) it generates the same link with a new unique id every time you press it.

Comment: AH, think I got an easier solution, dont want more then 1 link per user either so the easiest way is, to just execute the function one time. Would that be right? => $(".url2").one("keyup", function(){request_my_URL();}).blur(function(){request_my_URL();});

Comment: Because what i see after reviewing my database, after the user types in an url, its gets saved to database and replaced by the shortened ref link, then this link gets again cut by the funtion, generates a new one and so one. As I dont want to have more than one link per textarea input it would probably the best to let the function only run one time when an url was found, after that no more urls should go trough the jquery function.

Comment: sry didn't know i'm pretty new in here :)